# Update Facebook Status from Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, html

I have a web application that uses HTML5, javascript, and jquery to send messages to and from people. I want to now make it possible to update your Facebook status from the webpage. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: try?how u manage to post such question??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have to do the following:

1. Create an application which will do the posting on your Facebook user's behalf
2. Have the Facebook user allow permissions for the application to post for the user (publish_stream permission). You should get an access token for this
3. Once you have an access token with the correct permissions, you need to send a Facebook Graph API request to **https://graph.facebook.com/[FB UID]/post?access_token=[access token]**, with POST parameters defining your status update. You can see the parameters here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/
4. If successful, the API call should return a POST ID so you can query the post for stuff like likes, comments, etc.

You can check out my Facebook Graph API tutorial here:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/wrangling-with-the-facebook-graph-api/

The tutorial is actually what you're looking for - a website that uses the Graph API to post to different Facebook pages/accounts. It's a bit outdated (e.g. Facebook removed the offline_access permission already), but with a little tweaking it should work flawlessly again.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look into using the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). Actually updating your Facebook status is a rather lengthy process to describe here but their documentation will get you started in the right direction.